# Python - Script Imrovement Suggestions

Tags: python

I am pretty new to Python.  I completed a challenge using a script I created.  I am sure it can be improved upon and more efficient.  I would appreciate suggestions to improve and simplify this script for future use.  The challenge was to read from a file and run the value found in the file through base 16, base 32, & base 64 five times each.  Below is the script I created.  The last variable (v64) contains the flag.

Thank You!

```
>     import base64
>     
>     i = 0
>     with open('encodedflag.txt') as fp:
>         v = fp.read()
>     
>     while i <= 4:
>         decoded_16 = base64.b16decode(v)
>         v = decoded_16
>         i += 1
>     
>     v32 = v
>     
>     j = 0 
>     
>     while j <= 4:
>         decode_32 = base64.b32decode(v32)
>         v32 = decode_32
>         j += 1
>     
>     v64 = v32
>     
>     k = 0
>     
>     while k <= 4: 
>         decode_64 = base64.b64decode(v64)
>         v64 = decode_64
>         k += 1
>     
>     print(v64)
```

Comment: I'd suggest taking it to CodeReview because SO doesn't normally deal with working code.

Comment: Put your questions here https://codereview.stackexchange.com/, as that is the right location. This exchange is for people with non working code.

Comment: You can actually do everything in a single loop.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions.  I'll move it.

Comment: `for i in range(5):` is always easier to read than a while loop like that.